# Extract time in momentjs object to use with inBetween function

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to get the current time and use it in my a conditional if statement to see if it's between a set of times. I've tried to use `moment().isBetween(nine, ten)` where nine and ten are strings (just like it says to use in the docs) but moment() returns the day as well. I've also tried `moment().format("hh:mm A").isBetween(nine, ten)` but format turns everything into a string and obviously cannot use isBetween. How can I extract the current time and use it in isBetween? If it is easier to use the Date object in vanilla JS, I'm all ears.

```
// what I've tried. example 1
let nine = "9:00"
let nineFormat = moment(nine, "HH:mm A").format("hh:mm A");
let ten = "10:00"
let tenFormat = moment(ten, "HH:mm A").format("hh:mm A");

if(moment().isBetween(nineFormat,tenFormat){
     console.log("I'm here");
}

//I've also tried but doesn't work because test is a string. example 2
let test = moment().format("hh:mm A");

if(test.isBetween(nineFormat,tenFormat){
     console.log("I'm here");
}
```

Here is the error that I'm getting for example 1

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
>   Arguments: 
>   [0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: 09:00 AM, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]
>   Error

Comment: Can you create a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a closing bracket: `if(moment().isBetween(nineFormat,tenFormat){` should be `if(moment().isBetween(nineFormat,tenFormat)){`.

You should also not format the dates you are passing to isBetween, or at least format them as a standard ISO string.

```
let nine = moment("9:00", "HH:mm A");
let ten = moment("10:00", "HH:mm A");

if (moment().isBetween(nine, ten)) {
     console.log("I'm here");
}
```